# Handling nested elements with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-agility-pack

So I'm trying to write code to convert HTML into Markdown for a Windows Store App.  So far I've had a good deal of success with HtmlAgilityPack, but I've run into an issue.

Here's some sample HTML

```
<p>A paragraph of text, including some text which is <strong>bolded</strong></p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

I process this with the following code.

```
foreach (var x in doc.Descendants.Where(x => x.Name == "p").ToList())
{
    x.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode(x.InnerHtml 
            + Environment.NewLine 
            + Environment.NewLine),
        x);
}
```

The expected output is

```
A paragraph of text, including some text which is <strong>bolded</strong>

Another paragraph
```

But the actual output is

```
A paragraph of text, including some text which is 

Another paragraph
```

It seems like as soon as it hits a nested node it just ignores everything after that point.

If I have a rule before to process `strong` tags, then the output is as expected. However, I can't rely on doing things "in order" because then there's no way to handle things such as a `p` within a `p`

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE** this is for a Windows Store app, and uses the WinRT version of HTMLAgilityPack which does *not* support XPath

Answer (score 0):

`CreateNode` method will return the first sibling only from the parsed html. That is why you won't get bold tag. So you have to find all siblings and insert them back in place of your para node and remove the para node.

This code can get you started:

```
foreach (var x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "p").ToList())
{
    var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(x.InnerHtml + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (var child in node.ParentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        x.ParentNode.InsertBefore(child, x);
    }
    x.ParentNode.RemoveChild(x);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is right? I havent tested yet but surely `node` won't have any children since we just created it?

Comment: My code is based on the original source code for [CreateNode](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs). When you input a piece of html it might contain other tags which you're losing while creating a new node. Looks like undesired behavior to me, but until that is fixed, you can get all siblings rather than first one from the above code. Its rather a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Yes but in your example you create a textnode called `node` with CreateNode and then you immediately loop over `node.ParentNode.ChildNodes`. At that point `node` has no parents or children?